# How do I sort an Access report on each header similar to an Excel Pivot Table?

Tags: ms-access

Currently, I have an Access report displaying data like a pivot table:

1. Category1 Header

   - Category1:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Sum([CP_Time])
2. Category2 Header

   - Category2:::::::::::::::::::::::::::Sum([CP_Time])
3. Detail

   - Category3::::::::::::::::[CP_Time]

I need all three levels to sort numerically as follows:

1. Category1:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::10

   - Category2:::::::::::::::::::::5

     - Category3::::::::3
     - Category3::::::::2
   - Category2:::::::::::::::::::::5

     - Category3::::::::4
     - Category3::::::::1

However, I can only get category 3 to sort numerically based on the associated value. The other two are sorted alphabetically based on the category itself. I have tried different groupings, calculated fields in the report as well as directly in the query but nothing so far has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Manually create a report of [sub-reports](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-use-subreports-816f987a-4615-4058-8f20-ce817093bb33), based on summary [sub-queries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-data-by-using-a-query-430a669b-e7fd-4c4b-b154-8c8dbbe41c8a#bm4). Then use the Report Designer's [Group and Sort](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-sort-order-with-a-table-query-form-or-report-4f255441-7326-486a-97ad-7760e8b0880b#bm3) feature to customize the grouping and sorting, as demonstrated below. You can customize a wizard generated report, but it can be frustrating, due to its limitations and the invisible items it inserts.

The following example, based on Northwind data,  creates a 3 level outline report, sorted at each level using the Report Designer's grouping and sorting features. It does not include sub-queries and sub-reports, which require advance tutorials. I've linked two tutorials above and one [here](https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/creating-and-editing-reports.html). The last image shows a mod of the first report where sorting on a subtotal based on a sub-query overrides sorting by Order Date.

_

**Based on a Simple Database Query**
[image: Database Design View]
_

**Manually Group and Sort in Design View**
[image: Design View]
_

**Outline Report, Sorted on Three Categories**
[image: Print Preview]

-

**Outline Report: Sorting on subtotal, based on sub-query**
[[image]][8s]

Comment: Pretty close. This is about to the point I get stuck. I need that report to have sub totals on every level and have the sub totals sorted numerically and not the data itself.

Comment: Subreports and as @June7 said, then mysteriously deleted, subqueries.

Comment: @hunter101-360 I've edited my answer to reflect your feedback, and included links to advanced tutorials.